# Qt Text Edit with a fixed number of input lines

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit

I have a Qt "Text Edit" widget in my Gui and this widget is used to log something.
I add every line(s) this way:

```
QString str;
str = ...
widget.textEdit_console->append(str);
```

by this way the Text Edit height will increase more and more after each new line.
I want it act like a terminal in this case, I mean after some number (that I set) of lines entered, for each new line the first line of Text Edit being deleted to prevent it being too big!
should I use a counter with every new line entered and delete the first ones after counter reached it's top or there is better way that do this automatically after

```
widget.textEdit_console->append(str);
```

called ?

Comment: If you are creating a logger, you should use a `QListWidget` (or equivalent).  That way each log entry is a discrete unit rather than the whole thing being a monolithic block of text.  Adding functionality like what you want becomes very simple as well.

Comment: @cmannett85: Now that you mention it, it's the obvious solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank [cmannett85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498437/cmannett85) for your advise but for some reason I prefer 'Text Edit',
I solved my problem this way:

```
void mainWindow::appendLog(const QString &str)
{
    LogLines++;
    if (LogLines > maxLogLines)
    {
        QTextCursor tc = widget.textEdit_console->textCursor();
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
        tc.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
        tc.removeSelectedText(); // this remove whole first line but not that '\n'
        tc.deleteChar(); // this way the first line will completely being removed
        LogLines--;
    }
    widget.textEdit_console->append(str);
}
```

I still don't know is there any better more optimized way while using 'Text Edit'

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to turn the vertical scroll-bar off:

```
 textEdit_console->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Comment: That won't automatically delete the first line, will it? The user will be able to bring it into view by simply cursoring up to it.

Comment: @TonyK ~> You're right. But I said it's the simplest way :). I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code move cursor to the first line and then select it until end of line, next it will delete the line:

```
widget.textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
widget.textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::EndOfLine, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
widget.textEdit->textCursor().deleteChar();
widget.textEdit->textCursor().deleteChar();
```